# Server API defensive design?

Tags: api, http, service

For a service REST API, for example, `http://service_host/stores/count=30`, will return 30 stores extracted from DB.

If someone put count=99999999, the service will spend quite a while to return all the stores. Shall I put a limit on the count parameter from the service side? Or shall I leave it to the client to enforce any limit they need?

Also, is it better to implement the validation of this count parameter (like valid type, positive value etc) on the service side? I tend to make the service strong and safe, but hesitate to put too much checking in it.

Is there any design convention to follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a limit on the parameter on the service side so that your service is reliable but at the same time you should provide the client with an option to fetch more items with separate requests. This is usually done by accepting 2 parameters - `offset` and `count`. The offset is the position of the first item to be returned and the count - the number of items, starting at `offset` to be returned.

Generally - don't let the client abuse your service. Implement meaningful limits in the service so that it's reliable and let the client do the heavy work (create and send multiple requests). At the same time support those multiple request and document that especially if the service is to be used by a 3rd party developer.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, don't rely on clients to behave nicely. **Always** protect yourself on the server side. Validate types, enforce limits on parameters, check for non-valid input. Otherwise clients can bring your whole system down unintentionally (not to mention malicious attacks).